# How to download image from internet using greasemonkey script?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

i am new to greasemonkey. I'd like to create scripts to change my favourite wep apps look and download images from web app like facebook.

I know some jquery and i will be able to find the image element. But i dont know how to save them in local file system.

Any help would be appreciative!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greasemonkey is not the tool for this.
GM will let you grab and insert external images into a page, but it cannot save images, or anything else, to the local file system. (This is by design -- as allowing JavaScript to save files is a proven security disaster.)

A pretty good extension for grabbing and saving lots of images is: [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) .

If you want to grab images automatically, you'll have to write a scraper application or your own web-application.

Greasemonkey *can* send images to your webserver, which can save them.

Comment: Thanks. After i install DownThemAll, the download link which i created on the images in facebook, shows download option on right click.